# Replace double quotes about a javascript function in perl

Tags: regex, perl, cgi

I have am using cgi to read javascript objects (JSON), which have javascript functions enclosed in double quotes, and my requirement is to removes the quotes around any such javascript function.

Eg:

```
"value" : "helloWorld('hello')"
```

The above is an extract from the key value pair, and i need to get something like this after the substitution operation.

```
 "value" : helloworld('hello')
```

So, the end-result must have the quotes removed from the javascript function.I am using perl for cgi programming and would like an answer in the same.

Comment: Regex is not going to do the trick here. A javascript function can be constructed in so many ways that you would have to re-implement the javascript syntax in regex in order to properly parse it.

Comment: What do you mean by "removing the quotes"? Are you asking it to be parsed as if the quotes were not there? How would you be able to tell that it's not just text that happens to have parentheses in it, as opposed to an actual function call?

Comment: Lindrian you are right.I will be calling javascript functions by their method signatures(no anonymous functions).Also, i will be having these functions inside a nested json object.So, i think using regular expression for detecting functions, would do the trick for me!

Comment: @Qantas 94 Heavy, i needed to remove quotes from javascript functions, as I was trying to generate ExtJS apps dynamically,which i am certainly achieving doing the above way.Also, I was able to figure out a RE expression for my question

Comment: Since you were _able to figure out a RE_, how about posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove anything. JSON::XS or whatever JSON parser you like will return `helloworld('hello')` for the value of that key.

```
use JSON::XS qw( decode_json );
my $json = q{{"value" : "helloworld('hello')"}};
say decode_json($json)->{value};    # helloworld('hello')
```

All you need to do is write a function similar to `encode_json` that outputs in the format you desire rather than JSON (i.e. with the appropriate values unquoted).

Then, your code will be:

```
print encode_myformat(decode_json($json));
```

Comment: Actually, the function will be a part of a  nested json structure and I need to remove the quotes from specific occurrences of the method.Will your approach, help me in what i want to achieve?

Comment: Everything I said still applies.